# Is there an easy way to find the index of a newly created array item using bracket notation in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with a script that I am iterating through an array and assigning values in that array to another array. I need the index of the newly created array item so I can manipulate it further. When you create a new item in an array using the `$array[] =` method is there an easy way to determine what index was assigned without looping through the array and evaluating or using array_search?

***Current Code***

```
foreach($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item['some_index'];
}
```

***Only solution I've found so far, but seems clunky***

```
foreach($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item['some_index']; //has a value of 'value1'
   $key = array_search('value1',$array2)
}
```

Comment: Usually you would build all of the data for the new item and then add it.  Creating a temporary array for `$item`, and the last thing is to do `$array2[] = $item;`

Comment: Duh, I don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks!

Comment: Question is, why do you need the key?  May be a better way to go about the entire thing.

Comment: There probably is a better way but the project was dumped in my lap to "fix" a specific feature so I'm trying to avoid rewriting a lot of the code until I have more time to overhaul the whole app (previous dev didn't comment anything and the code is all over the place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your array is numeric you could just do it like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item['some_index']; //has a value of 'value1'
   $key = count($array2) -1;
}
```

Or you could also just add a $counter variable, like this (if $array2 is empty):

```
 $counter = 0;  
 foreach($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item['some_index']; //has a value of 'value1'
   $key = $counter;
   $counter++;
}
```

EDIT:
As mentioned by  AbraCadaver, if your array might not start at 0 you should use the end() and key()-function to get the key at the last position:

```
foreach($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item['some_index']; 
   end($array2);
   $key = key($array2);
}
```

Comment: The first solution will work nicely for my application. Second one not so much because $array2 may not be empty when it reaches this portion of the code but you identified that caveat :) Thanks!

Comment: The first one won't work if your array doesn't start at 0, I would look at the other answer using `end` and `key` that will work for any array.

Comment: Good point, the array does start at 0 though so it will do the trick for now until I can find time to eliminate the need for the key completely.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting values that way doesn't alter the array pointer but you can always force it yourself with [end()](https://php.net/end) so you're able to use [key()](https://php.net/key) (and, incidentally, [current()](https://php.net/current)):

```
foreach ($array1 as $item) {
   $array2[] = $item;
   end($array2);
   echo "$item inserted as ", key($array2), PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/P5GOo)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, given the limitations you noted in the comment on the original question, I'd recommend using [`array_push`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) instead as it returns the new count that you could use to determine the new index.

```
<?php
foreach($array1 as $item) {
           // pushes value onto array
           // subtracts 1 from the returned count to calculate the new index
    $key = (array_push($array2, $item['some_index']) - 1);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for originally and even looked at the doc for array_push but overlooked that it returned a count. I steered away from it after reading that if you are adding only one element it's not advised to use array push since it's an extra function call.

Comment: The extra function call is a micro-optimization that I wouldn't sweat. Also, to be fair, anything you do to solve this will involve an extra operation-- `array_push`, `array_search`, `count`, `$counter++`, etc.  I'm glad you found a solution that works, though!